# How would I make a integer array (of 0's and 1's) into a char?

Tags: c, byte, bit

What would be a way to convert an array like this

```c
int bit_array[8] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
```

into a char? (assuming bit_array is in ascii or similar)

for example an end result would preferably be like this:

```c
int bit_array[8] = {0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0}; // h
int bit_array2[8] = {0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1}; // i
char byte;
char byte2;
byte = funny_function(bit_array);
byte2 = funny_function(bit_array2);
printf("%s%s",byte,byte2); //out: "hi"
```

Comment: You might cast integers to bits then left shift a byte which has initial value 0 with the array elements. Then you would simply return that byte.

Comment: `printf("%s%s",byte,byte2); //out: "hi"` Characters are not strings. Use `%c`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without using a function call, you can do this with a loop in the body of `main()`.

```
int main() {
    // Only need 7 'bits'.
    // Let compiler measure size.
    // Use 1 byte 'char' instead of multibyte 'int'
    char bits[][7] = {
        {1,1,0,1,0,0,0}, // h
        {1,1,0,0,1,0,1}, // e
        {1,1,0,1,1,0,0}, // l
        {1,1,0,1,1,0,0}, // l
        {1,1,0,1,1,1,1}, // o
    };

    // Simply use a loop, not a function
    for( int i = 0; i < sizeof bits/sizeof bits[0]; i++ ) {
        char c = 0;

        // 7 bit values are 'accummulated' into 'c'...
        for( int ii = 0; ii < sizeof bits[0]/sizeof bits[0][0]; ii++ )
            c = (char)( (c << 1) | bits[i][ii] ); // Magic happens here

        putchar( c );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

(Friendly) output:

```
hello
```

EDIT:

As above, alternative version if output limited to only single case alphabet (fewer bits).

```
int main() {
    // Only need 5 'bits'.
    char low_bits[][5] = {
        {0,1,0,0,0}, // h
        {0,0,1,0,1}, // e
        {0,1,1,0,0}, // l
        {0,1,1,0,0}, // l
        {0,1,1,1,1}, // o
    };

    // Simply use a loop, not a function
    for( int i = 0; i < sizeof low_bits/sizeof low_bits[0]; i++ ) {
        char *cp = low_bits[i]; // for clarity (brevity)

        // Magic happens here...
        char c = (char)(cp[0]<<4 | cp[1]<<3 | cp[2]<<2 | cp[3]<<1 | cp[4] );

        putchar( c | 0x40); // uppercase. use 0x60 for all lowercase.
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

(Not so friendly) output (unless calling to distant person):

```
HELLO
```

Comment: Thankyou! I only had the function because I couldn't think of anything better to put

Answer (score 1):

`printf("%s%s",byte,byte2); //out: "hi"` will not printf anything and is wrong. `%s` expects a pointer to char referencing null character terminated C string and you pass integers (`char` is an integer).

It has to be:`printf("%c%c",byte,byte2);`

```
int funny_function(const int *bit_array)
{
    int result = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {   
        result <<= 1;
        result += !!bit_array[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

in non zero `bit_array` element value is considered `1`.

Comment: did you mean `result += bit_array[i]`? You should not increment `i`.you do not need !!. Also, bitwise arithmetic might be a bit better. Also, checking array size would be a good idea.

Comment: @Serge indeed.  Late night

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are certain that each item contains either 1 or 0, then it's as simple as this:

```
char funny_function (const int array[8])
{
  char result = 0;
  for(size_t i=0; i<8; i++)
  {
    result |= array[i] << (7-i);
  }
  return result;
}
```

That is:

- Take the 1st array item of `0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0`, left shift it 7 bits = 0x00, OR with 0x00 == 0x00.
- Take the 2nd array item of `0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0`, left shift it 6 bits = 0x40, OR with 0x00 == 0x40.
- Take the 3rd array item of `0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0`, left shift it 5 bits = 0x20, OR with 0x40 == 0x60.
- And so on.